# Unable to push data to Firebase onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

So I've recently been messing with Firebase and I came across an issue I need some help fixing. So I'm trying to send the data from the user input to Firebase, and for that data to show up in the specified div, but the data isn't showing up in my Firebase, or in that div...

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<form>
    <input name="name" class="form-control" type="name" placeholder="Title" id="titleInput" />
    <br/>
    <textarea id="postInput" name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
    <hr/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="submitPost()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my JQuery Code (EDITED):

```
function submitPost() {
     var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://EXAMPLE.firebaseio.com/');
     var name = $('#titleInput').val();
     var text = $('#postInput').val();
     myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
     $('#postInput').val('');

     myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
          var post = snapshot.val();
          displayUserPost(post.name, post.text);
     })
     function displayUserPost(name, text) {
         $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#PostsDiv'));
         $('#PostsDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#PostsDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
     }
 };
```

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a very good debugging medium. Did you set a breakpoint in your `submitPost()` method and if so, does it get triggered? If so, do the values of `name` and `text` get read from the inputs correctly? If so, do any error messages show up in the JavaScript console?

Comment: One problem: your variable is named `post`: `var post = snapshot.val();`, but you try to read properties from `message`: `displayUserPost(message.name, message.text);`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So I've fixed the code as shown above.  I tried again locally and this time, the post showed up for a split second, then the page redirected to `/index.html?name=Test&content=Test`.  The data is _still_ not in Firebase...And there are no breakpoints, the console doesn't show any errors as well.

Comment: Because your button is of type `submit`, it will submit the form, which will refresh the page. If you change the type of the button to `button` it should stop doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're dealing with asynchronous data flow, so you should listen for the data outside of the submitPost function.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://EXAMPLE.firebaseio.com/');
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var post = snapshot.val();
  displayUserPost(post.name, post.text);
});

function submitPost(e) {
  var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://EXAMPLE.firebaseio.com/');
  var name = $('#titleInput').val();
  var text = $('#postInput').val();
  myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
  $('#postInput').val('');
  e.preventDefault();
}

function displayUserPost(name, text) {
  $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#PostsDiv'));
  $('#PostsDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#PostsDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much! In fact, to show my gratitude I would like to share the [link](http://bordium.tk) to which this will be used with you! Thank you! Class was about to end but you helped right before it did! I'm so grateful! Being 13, I don't have many  people to ask these kinds of questions to, as most kids my age prefer to game all day. Again, thanks a million!

Comment: Looks awesome! Glad to see you getting involved at such a young age. Feel free to ask more questions. Try using http://JSBin.com or http://plnkr.co to reproduce your problems and we'll be able to collaborate that way :)